# Undefinded index: satuan in insertstoragedata.php

Tags: php, undefined

I'm new in PHP and I'm getting this error:

```
Undefinded index: satuan in D:\xampp\htdocs\Belajar\data\insertstoragedata.php on line 11
```

I couldn't find any solution online, so maybe someone can help me.

Here is the code:

```
$satuan             =   $_POST['satuan'];
```

thats the 11 line,can anyone help me??? I really can't understand why

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST['satuan'])){
    $satuan = $_POST['satuan'];
} else{
    $satuan = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this

```
<form action="insertstoragedata.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="satuan">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

In `insertstoragedata.php`

```
$satuan = $_POST['satuan'];
```

> **Note: make sure `name=""` is correct. Its Case Sensitive**
>
> And possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this..

```
$satuan  = (isset($_POST['satuan']) ? $_POST['satuan'] : null);
```